# Highlight a word in a row of a table in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an row object say user which contains key value pair of column and value of that column.
Now i want to highlight all the occurrences of a particular word in that row and then return that updated row.Reactjs table

I was  trying something like this but it didn't work

```
const searched = searchVal;
if (searched !== "") {

            Object.entries(user).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (value.includes(searched))
    {
            
            const re = new RegExp(searched, "g");
            const newText = value.replace(re, `<mark>${searched}</mark>`);
            value = newText;
          
          }
          return origData[index];
        }

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```js
const searched = 'jo'


const user = {
 name: "john",
 lastname: "doe"

}

const highlight = (obj, search) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => [key, value.replace(new RegExp(search, 'ig'), `<mark>${search}</mark>`)]))


console.log(highlight(user, 'jo'))
```

Comment: but i want to permanently highlight that cell in my table